# KineticJS web-app with draggable content is extremely laggy and keeps crashing android & iPhones

Tags: android, ios, html, performance, kineticjs

I've made an app with one layer per page and a swipe functionality to switch between them (like Android Homescreen) and it works great on my desktop-pc with Google Chrome. The major problem is, that the swipe-functionality has so serious lag issues, that it sometimes takes 5 or more seconds to redraw the stage at the desired point. Also, while starting the web-application, it causes some browsers (Dolphin on my HTC One X) to crash and on the others ones it takes ages to load. The weird thing about this is, that the laggy behaviour really gets better, when the device is held in landscape mode.

This issue hassles me quite a lot, so I would be super happy if someone of you could take a sneak peek at my work.

An extra question regarding this setup is the following: Can I make a layer or shape static, that it doesn't get dragged around with the draggable stage?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/437#issuecomment-17671540

This is what Eric Rowell, the creator of KineticJS says about my problem, I've tried resizing it, but that doesn't resolve my problem. 
So if anyone has the time to take a look at my code, I would be very glad ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured out how to solve my problem!!! :D

As Eric stated something about "viewport" I went for a walk around the internet and found out, that the initial resolution which was taken to calculate the stage size was much higher (960px width instead of the 700andsomething) than the actual resolution of the iPad etc., so I set the initial viewport with this little code snippet

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

at the actual device resolution and my performance problems were gone.